# why do I get this exception error-Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. head was 0xFFFFFFFFCBB1E630

Tags: c

The  line head->data = (int)1; , throws the above exception - Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. head was 0xFFFFFFFFCBB1E630. What could be the reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void print_nodes(struct Node* head);

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void print_nodes(struct Node* head) {
    struct Node* current = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d", current->data);
    }
}

void main() {
    struct Node* head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* first = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data = 1;
    head->next = first;

    first->data = 2;
    first->next = second;

    second->data = 3;
    second->next = NULL;

    print_nodes(head);
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `current`? Just use `head`. `current->next` is not initialized.

Comment: When that is fixed, `while (current->next != NULL)` will be an infinite loop when `current->next != NULL`. Should be `struct Node* current = head` and inside the loop, `current = current->next`. Or, just work with `head` directly in `print_nodes()` as it's a *copy* of the list's head.

Comment: How did you get this to compile without including `<stdlib.h>` and `<malloc.h>`?

Comment: Thank you. you all are right. I have to assign struct Node* current = head; and run while (current) . i don't get the error anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `print_nodes()`, no need to allocate.

```
//struct Node* current = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
struct Node* current = head;
```

Even better, start from the `head` rather than `.next`.

```
void print_nodes(const struct Node* current) {
    while (current) {
        printf("%d", current->data);
        current = current->next
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You helped me fix it

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if head was a valid pointer?  Probably not.

```
struct Node* head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
If(0==head) return 1;
head->data = 1;
```

Comment: It's good practice, but not the cause of the fault here.

Comment: Thank you. I have applied what you suggested.